# Write a program that reads input up to # and reports the number of times that the sequence ei occurs

Tags: c, if-statement, controls, branch

Write a program that reads input up to # and reports the number of times that the sequence ei occurs

I have this question and I found a code here for this but I'm unable to figure out what the int c1 part does. Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int c;
    int ei_count = 0;
    while ((c = getchar())!= '#') {
        if (c == 'e') {
            int c1 = getchar();
            if (c1 == 'i')
                ei_count++;
        }
    }
    printf("ei appeared %d times\n", ei_count);
    return(0);
}
```

My question is, how does the if condition work? Can someone please explain ?
I'm new at C

Comment: Your program will get stuck at EOF/input-error: `getchar` returns -1 on error.

Comment: The getchar() gets the next character typed in. The while loop assigned the character to c and exits if it is a #. If it is an 'e' then it gets the next character and saves it in c1 and if c1 contains an 'i' is adds one to the count.

Comment: Also, won't get the `ei` if in `eei`.

Comment: your program has problems with inputs like "...eei..." or "...e#"

Answer (score 2):

The `c1`-part is a broken try at scanning the second part of `ei`, they could have reused `c` without introducing more errors.

Better alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int c, last = 0, ei_count = 0;
  while ((c = getchar()) >= 0 && c != '#') {
    ei_count += last && c == 'i';
    last = c == 'e';
  }
  printf("ei appeared %d times\n", ei_count);
}
```

Corrected errors:

- neither `ei` nor `#` recognized after `e`.
- infinite loop on EOF / input error.

Random facts:

- `main` has an implicit `return 0;` just before the closing brace.
- `getchar()` returns an `int`, so it can return -1 on failure and an `unsigned char` converted to int on success. Always check for failure.
- logical and comparison operators always return 0 or 1.
- 0 is logical false, all else is logical true.
- `return` is not a function call: Use `return 0;` without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

That part you mentioned is a way to find a pattern like "ei". At the first moment the code try to find the 'e' character in a loop, and then, once it is found, the code checks if the next char is the letter 'i'. Case not, start again the loop to find another 'e' char.

This is not an good approach since there is no error verification during the getchar() operation and you can fall on a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Oversimplified, it's just a state machine.

Stepping through line-by-line:

- `while ((c = getchar())!= '#') {`

Read input and assign it to the variable `c`. If that read in char is anything but `#`, execute the body of the while, otherwise jump over it.

- `if (c == 'e') {`

If the read in character is an `e`, then we want to execute the internal block. If it's not, skip to the end of this block.

- `int c1 = getchar();`

Read another character.

- `if (c1 == 'i') ei_count++;`

If the new character is an i, then increment the counter of found items.

- `}` close if (if e was found)
- `}` close while.

It's worth pointing out there is a very clear flaw in the logic flow, however. Think about what happens if you have  the input "eei".

Answer (score 0):

In C, *char* and *int* data types are pretty much the same thing. In an assignment statement, the final result of the calculations are converted to the type of the variable being assigned to. Probably in this example, the author of this code assumed that the value returned by *getchar()* function which is of type *int* cannot be assigned to a *char* variable. You can use a *char* type for the *c1* variable, since the *getchar()* function returns the ASCII code of the next character in the input, and the value is automatically converted to *char* during assingment. In the next *if* statement, you can easily compare the value of *c1* with the character value *i*.

This code is a little bit buggy, for if you enter *e#* as an input, the program hangs. The reason is that *c1 = getchar();* statement in the *if* block assigns '#' value to variable c1, and the comparison obviously fails, and at the next iteration of the *while* loop, *getchar()* returns a value after the '#' character in the input stream, which is a garbage value unless you entered more other characters after the '#' character.

Here's my code with a few fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
char ch, next;
int ei_cnt = 0;

while((ch = getchar()) != '#') {
    if(ch == 'e') {
        next = getchar();
        if(next == '#')
            break;
        if(next == 'i')
            ei_cnt++;
    }
}

printf("ei substring occured %d %s.\n", ei_cnt, 
    ei_cnt == 1 ? "time" : "times");

return 0;
```

}